# WPF - Export XAML content to file (PDF or Word)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, pdf, ms-word

I have a pretty straightforward WPF application, but with a lot of forms, nearly 80, spread out to UserCcontrol xaml files and navigated with TabControl on a main Window file. Some of those forms contain a lot of data, but basically everything is broken down to TextBlock, TextBox, Label, Grid, RadioButton and ComboBox controls.

I am done with everything, but there is a requirement that everything at the end should be exported to a file - either PDF, or Word. Is there an easy way to do that? I don't have a requirement to have the same style and formatting. I only need the text - question and given answer, either text, or chosen option.

I have searched the web and saw many solutions, but PdfSharp was the best, I believe. However, I do have a lot of forms and it would be an overkill to map every single user control in a loop or something, to write to file. Creating a bitmap or an image and print to file would not help, since I have text boxes with scrolling and the whole text would not be visible in such cases.

What best would work for me would be a library that accepts, let's say, a user control and then prints its content on a page(s) of a file. Once again - I don't need any styling or formatting or images, just text.

Here is a small example of what one of the forms looks like, just to give you an idea:
[image]

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Hi, look for XamlWriter.Save method, it may help your case.

Answer (score 0):

I've looked for similar tools and there isn't much out there, especially if you are looking for something open-source.

The most straightforward approach will be using tools found in the [System.Windows.Automation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.automation?view=netframework-4.8) namespace. That should help you write some helper functions that can capture text from all of the elements in your controls.

This link should be helpful:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/ui-automation/obtain-text-attributes-using-ui-automation